# How to use ternary operator for colpan in angular js?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Is this the correct way to set the colspan value with the ternary operator?

```
colspan="((true && false) ? 9 : (true || false) ? 8 : 7)"
```

I'm not getting the exact result with this.

[image]

this is the output I'm getting.

Sorry for the outlines.

I'm expecting something like this

[image]

**Note:-**
columns are dynamic, which is why I need to add a ternary operator for this.

Comment: What does it mean `true && false` and `true || false`? Are they variables or something?

Comment: Yes, AngularJS expressions support nested ternaries. Your use of boolean literals makes the question confusing, but assuming they should be variables and that you wrap it all with `{{ }}`, this should work. Alternatively, consider moving the logic into a function and doing something like `colspan="{{getColSpan(var1, var2)}}"` (with better param names, of course)

Comment: Does it have to be calculated in the template? Could you put this information in the model? I recommend against the previous suggestion of calling a function in your binding, that is a bad practice that can cause performance issues.